# Start network connection with Java thread

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I'm using this Java code to start network connection with Java thread.

```
(new Thread(() ->
            {
                client.connectToServer(System.out, System.err);
                s = client.getConnectionStatus();
            })).start();
```

I also use another Java thread to to get the status of the connection:

```
new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (s != null)
                {
                    Platform.runLater(new Runnable()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void run()
                        {
                            actiontarget.setText(s);
                            p2.setVisible(false);
                        }
                    });

                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

But for some reason the code is not working. The interface is not updated. Can you tell me how to properly implement this?

Comment: I think s gets updated after the connection gets started because you only set the variable right after connecting, which might take some some time in another Thread.
Also try logging or updating the actiontarget right after getConnectionStatus()

Comment: You are sharing a variable between threads: is "s" volatile? If not each thread can keep a local value copy for better performance... and it never calls Platform.runLater...